# Defining "variables" in assembly language

Tags: assembly, gnu-assembler, att

I underdstand that this is extremely stupid quiestion, but I can't figure  an answer for some time
How do I correctly declare and define "variables" in GAS AT&T assembly language?
For example, I want buffer for 5 bytes, two 1-byte variables (initially with 0 value), 2-byte variable with 0 and 2-byte variable with 10.
This code doesn't work correctly, at least debugger says (on the first line of the program, after these declarations, just `nop` instruction) that `b` and `c` are big numbers instead of zeros.

```
.bss
    .lcomm r, 5

.data
    a:  .byte 0
    b:  .byte 0
    c:  .word 0
    d:  .word 10
```

Comment: It seems fine to me. Maybe your debugger reads `b` and `c` as `dwords`, and in that case, `b` and `c` may be `0x0a0000` and `0x0a00`, or bigger.

Comment: Or maybe the debugger shows the addresses not the values. You didn't show what you did in the debugger, and which one you use, but to print `a` you could do `x/b &a` in `gdb`.

Comment: That's how you define variables in GAS assembly. Your debugger probably doesn't know that `b` and `c` are supposed to be 8-bit and 16-bit numbers. The debugging information generated by assemblers isn't as good as that generated by compilers.

Comment: @user35443, my debugger is `kdbg`, if this matters.
And so what can I do in this situation?

Comment: @Construct How do you retrieve the contents of `b` and `c`? Have you tried explicitly specifying their size, like using `x/1b variable`?

Comment: @user35443, http://i.imgur.com/yxdA37l.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what you see in your "Watches" window:

```
a = 0 = 0x00 = 0x0000 = 0x00 0000 = 0x0000 0000

b = 167772160 = 16777216 * 10 = 0x1000000 * 0x0A = 0xA000000

c = 655360 = 65536 * 10 = 0x10000 * 0x0A = 0xA0000

d = 10 = 0x0A = 0x0000 000A
```

What does it mean? It means that your compiler did its job, but your debugger reads `c` and `b` as doublewords (4 bytes) instead of bytes.

When it reads in `b`, it reads its value `0x00`, `c`´s value `0x0000`, and `d`´s value `0x0A` on the top, together making it `0xA000000`.

Similar thing happens to `c`. `a` got lucky, as the next 4 bytes are zero, so the `a` is really zero.

However, this doesn't always have to be the case. Nothing says that there can't be any garbage after `d`, not to mention that variables equal to zero may appear in `.bss` (on a completely different memory location).

Comment: Thanks. But what can I do now? I can't use debugger for adequate watching my variables?

Comment: @Construct I'm not very familiar with `kdbg`, there may be some settings for it. If you were able to access (possibly underlying) `gdb` through some interface, or use gdb directly, your problem would be solved. 
You can still try to compile with `as -g`, `as -g3`, or `as -ggdb` and then load, so there would be some additional debugging information present for `kdbg`.